# Django admin pagination... how to add a custom button to show all rows

Tags: django, django-admin

In my code I've something like this (I'm using Django 1.6):

```
class CategoryAdmin(CategoryBaseAdmin):
    [...]
    list_per_page = 50
    [...]
```

But I want to give users the possibility to switch the table for displaying all rows... 
Something like a button (or a link) in the pagination bar... Is it possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Django 1.6 has an inbuilt thing called ModelAdmin.list_max_show_all set this value greater than the value that you're expecting would be the total number of resultset returned and the 'Show All' (appears in the form link) at bottom of page(area where you can switch pages).

[Here's](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.6/ref/contrib/admin/#django.contrib.admin.ModelAdmin.list_max_show_all) the link to django where you can find the explanation. Go ahead and add it to your class in admin.py.

Example :

> ```
>  class foo(admin.ModelAdmin):
>         list_display = ['feild1', 'feild2']
>         ordering     = ['feild1']
>         list_max_show_all = n
>         actions = ('action1', 'action2')
> ```

where n is your value (should be greater than the expaected number of resultset). And it should work. Hope that you're fine with the 'Show all' appearing as link.